# How to calculate unsaved changes in Code Mirror

Tags: javascript, diff, codemirror

I use a CodeMirror for displaying code on the HTML page. I have a version of the code which was saved in BD and when a user edits it in CodeMirror, I want to highlight unsaved changes like Visual Studio Code does:

[image]

I know that I can use method: `codeMirror.removeLineClass(line, 'gutter', 'my_class');` to add a border that shows that changes were done at the specific line. My problem is in the calculation of the changed lines. I tried to use `diff` and `diff2html` packages and calculates changes like this:

```
var diff = Diff.createTwoFilesPatch('some name', 'some name', cm.state.savedText, cm.getValue());
var diffInfo = Diff2Html.getJsonFromDiff(diff, options);
```

This approach gives me a diff and I can get changed lines from it: 
[image]

But this solution has a performance problem - it works slowly if a text contains more than 40 lines, and I will have large texts in CodeMirror.

I also tried to use history (the structure that `codeMirror.getDoc().getHistory()` returns) and highlight lines that are stored in 'changes' array, but it works only for new lines which were added. This approach doesn't work if the user removes the line.

What is the right way of calculation for such changes?

I was thinking of using the `change` event and tracking a specific change("+delete",
"+input"), then collect changed lines in special array. But this solution looks painful because in this case, I need to update this array manually if lines were added/deleted in the next iteration.

Is there a simpler way of how to do it?

Comment: You don't specify what server side languages you're using, but you should be able to use a third party diff library such as https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch There are also client side diff libraries such as https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff

Comment: I don't specify the server-side language, because I need to do this on the client, because a user should be able to edit the text like in normal IDE.  I've tried to use the github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff library (the 'createTwoFilesPatch' method that I mentioned in my question it's a method from this library). I'm wondering how this functionality is implemented in IDEs: do they highlight changed lines based on the diff or they keep a history of user's changes and highlight lines based on it.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've realized that even for big texts (~12 000 lines) approach with calculating the diff still works:

```
var diff = Diff.createTwoFilesPatch('some name', 'some name', cm.state.savedText, cm.getValue());
var diffInfo = Diff2Html.getJsonFromDiff(diff, options)
```

It takes ~30ms to calculate the diff for big text, and 5-6ms for small ones (~100lines). So for now it seems the most simple way for highlighting updated lines.